# Suggestions for improving how I loop through the values of a dictionary?

Tags: python, optimization, loops, dictionary

This is what I have been using:

```
for i in iter(SHAPES):
    SHAPES[i].drawOrder(97)
    SHAPES[i].alpha(CFG["SHP_alpha"])
    .
    .
```

This is what I thought about doing:

```
for i, v in app.SHAPES.items():
    v.drawOrder(97)
    v.alpha(CFG["SHP_alpha"])
    .
    .
```

Which of the two am I supposed to use? Are there any other ways of doing it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need the key, just ignore it and use `.itervalues()`. If you need both key and value, `.iteritems()` is indeed the way to go. Note that in Python 3, those got rid of the `iter` prefix and Python 2 `.values()` and `.items()` (which returned lists) are gone. They have their (rare) uses, but when you just iterate, there is no need to copy half of the dictionary.

And never call `iter` yourself unless you really need an iterator (e.g. for `next`). Which is hardly more often than never ;) `for i in iterable` already uses `iter(iterable)` implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the values in the dict.

```
for v in SHAPES.itervalues():
    v.drawOrder(97)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The option that gives the most **flexibility** for a dictionary is to use enumerate() and dict.iteritems().

```
for i, (k,v) in enumerate(SHAPES.iteritems()):
   print "My index is {0}, key is {1}, and value is {2}".format(i, k, v)
```

Comment: That's plain overkill for most use cases, including OP's. In fact, I think I *never* used `enumerate` with mappings...

Comment: Hence emphasis on flexibility.  OP is just curious about what is possible.

Comment: Given that a dictionary returns elements in random order, what is the added value of having `i`? The index of a pair returned by iteritems has no meaning at all...

Comment: #1) OrderedDict does.  #2) There are plenty of use cases. Flush a transaction or check the status of a thread every N calculations.